# Adding polygon to d3 vornoi causing an error

Tags: javascript, d3.js, polygon, vertices

I'd like to extend this example ( http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060366 ) and make a functionality so if the user clicks on one polygon, to add this polygon among others (plus the dot in the middle).
I have added these lines

```
.on("click", function () {
            svg.append("circle").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.mouse(this) + ")").attr("r", 1.5);
            vertices.push(d3.mouse(this));
        })
```

jsut after

```
.on("mousemove",....
```

and it works - the polygon is added BUT there is strange error happening on the function

```
    function polygon(d) {
    return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z";
}
```

saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined"
After I push the polygon to "vertices" I'm not calling this function but the error ocures anyway... Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error, as best as I can tell, is being caused by the fact that when you click there is an extra path that it expects to draw, but because your mouse pointer is exactly on the edge of the path the value (d) is undefined. You'll notice that the yellow highlighted area only updates after you move your mouse pointer.

This gives you a couple of solutions.

1. Hide the error. You can do this by adding `if (typeof d == 'undefined') return;` to the beginning of your `polygon` function.
2. 'Hacky' workaround - modify the mouse position on redraw. Add `vertices[0] = [vertices[0][0]- 5, vertices[0][1] + 5];` to the beginning of your `redraw` function. This will prevent the mouse from conflicting with the new polygon. Note that the `-5` and `+5` are arbitrary values.

Comment: First think I did was to add check for "d" but It looks too dirty to me so I've post this question. Thanks for your answer - I will use the second solution.